# Disabling Vaadin table tooltip while loading

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I am using a Vaadin TreeTable to show a bunch of items.
When clicking on a node I close all other nodes and open the clicked one.

Is there any way to avoid the tooltip displaying current range and total number of items?
I found out that this is a Vaadin feature but I didn't find any possibility to disable it..

Snippet from the Book of Vaadin:
"While the data is being loaded, a tooltip will be displayed that shows the current range and total number of items in the table." 
(at https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/components.table.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use css:

```
.v-table-scrollposition{ display: none !important;}
```